# Rigid body doesn't interact with an object with Curve modifier

Tags: modifiers, rigid-body-simulation

(blend file link at the bottom)
So i have this scene of a conveyor belt and boxes:

[image]

my box doesn't interact with the conveyor belt despite giving my conveyor belt this setting:
[image]

but, the box DOES interact with the conveyor belt's "EDIT MODE"
[image]

it's interacting with my conveyor belt before the "curve modifier" is applied.

sorry if i'm not that good at explaining with words. I try to give alot of pictures.

stackexchange I have visited that is related, but doesnt work for me:
[Passive rigid body physics not working with screw modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32578/passive-rigid-body-physics-not-working-with-screw-modifier)
.
[Rigid Body not working with Passive / Animated / Mesh / Deforming](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/213736/rigid-body-not-working-with-passive-animated-mesh-deforming/213831#213831)

here's my blend file: (blend-exchange is processing for 1 hour already and is still not uploading my 8MB blend file)
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xpb_0X4Iui3rqxS6RAMs3beX9Q9u9sCK?usp=sharing

alternate link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W7N3mXyivZGuTIHP9U5juXWBrqpa75XP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide blend file, might be a lot of reasons

Comment: I'm trying to upload my blend file to blend-exchange, but it's been processing for around 1 hour.... I'll post a google drive link instead

Comment: your link does not work. i can see the name of the file, but i cannot download

Comment: I've added extra links , sorry

Comment: i've read some posts (i linked above), when i set the "shape" to mesh, and the source to "final", it does calculate modifier. Somehow doesn't work for me

Comment: hmm ... that is weird ... it works under 2.79 (with Final) but doesn't in 2.93 or 3.0 ... so probably could be post as a bug ... check bug report list if it is not reported yet. Also in your second link it is marked as a bug - so what is the question? Also here is some kind of solution for now https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/221054/2214 didnt study it so probably not helpful in your case.

Comment: Agree with vklidu. I am pretty sure it is a bug. This worked (not as you did it, but there is also an answer of Brecht here and even if i use his settings, i didn't get it worked).

Comment: i tried the link vklidu sent yesterday too, unfortunately its also interacting with the un-deformed object for me.... 
its a bug indeed probably

Comment: I know I'm WAY late to the party but I am currently having a similar problem and from looking at a few other forums I tried rotating the curve by 180 degrees on the x-axis and it seemed to sort things out